# Formatting a Dojo list item's icon

Tags: html, css, mobile, dojo, html-lists

I'm trying to set the sizing for my list item's icon. Basically, I need to set the height and width to be 27 pixels whilst the image is actually 54 pixels wide and high. This is for use with retina graphics so that it will display properly on older and newer iPhones. Here is my code:

```
<ul data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TabBar">
            <li id="footerHomeButton" class="sizing" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TabBarButton"
                icon1="images/new/home_icon@2x.png" onclick="WL.Page.load(INDEX.loadPage(0));">Home</li>
```

I have tried everything I can think of, from simple height and width tags, to CSS modifications, to Dojo sizings and nothing works. This is rather frustrating, hopefully someone else has encountered a similar problem? Why they don't include icon height and width parameters is beyond me, unless I've missed this in the documentation and you actually can?

Please help! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me using css like below. Hope it'd help. Thanks.

```
img.mblListItemIcon {
    height: 29px;
    width: 29px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```